# Get child products of configurable product via Service Contract / API

Tags: magento2, api, magento-2.0, associate-products, service-contract

In Magento 2, is it possible to **get the associated simple products of a configurable product, via Service Contracts?**

The only reference to the product type that I can find is `ProductInterface::getTypeId()`, but nothing that gives access to the underlying product type instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do it by using the `getChildren` method from `Magento/ConfigurableProduct/Api/LinkManagementInterface` class.

You will have to [use the sku as a parameter](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/Api/LinkManagementInterface.php)

Comment: Ah, I forgot that it's a completely separate module now, thanks!

Comment: @fschmengler yeah I tend to forget it too ^^ same goes for Bundle / Downloadable / Grouped